# Net group command

Tags: windows, active-directory, command-line-interface, automation, windows-net-command

I'm working on an automation project, and I need to add members to a specific group using a command-line approach. Currently, I'm using the **net group** command like this:

```
net group "group name" user /add /domain
```

However, the group name can change, which isn't ideal for automation. Is there a way to use the group email address instead of the group name in an equivalent command line? The email address remains constant and doesn't change !! can someone please help me through this

thanks alot :)

Answer (score 2):

Use Powershell for this.

Read in the group and users in a variable first. The users can either be hardcoded or like for the group - we can apply a filter, query AD and add the returned user(s) to the group.

```
$Group = Get-ADGroup -Filter "mail -eq 'group@example.com'"
$Users = Get-ADUser -Filter [...]

Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group -Members $Users
```